# Can I uninstall Xcode but keep Simulator?

Tags: xcode, xcode-simulator

I do not want Xcode, I only want Simulator. Are they different apps? Can I uninstall Xcode but keep Simulator?

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can use the storage management tool in System Information app to delete portions of Xcode like simulators, SDK versions, cached data and more.

[image]

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206996

> Choose Apple menu  > About This Mac, then click Storage
> Click the Manage button to open the Storage Management window